# Custom commentary for urls in Springfox Swagger UI (api-doc)

Tags: swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

I have a spring boot aplication with springfox-swagger2 and springfox-swagger-ui (version 2.9.2) genereting nice interactive api documentation based on my `@Controller` components and their `@RequestMapping` annotated methods.

I would llike to enhance generated documentation by custom commentary (e.g. via javadoc). Is there a way to achieve this? I have read through several tutorials and i am none the viser...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered the solution. The `@Api` annotation for controllers and `@ApiOperation` for mothods have attributes that are displayed in swagger UI.